# PHP+ MySQL - Fetch array loops many times

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem my code. The mysql_fetch_array output repeating same value. This is my code :

```
$sql= "SELECT client.resID AS resID, client.resName AS resName, menu.id AS mid, menu.name AS mname, facilities.name AS fname, facilities.id AS fid FROM client INNER JOIN menu ON client.resID = menu.resID INNER JOIN facilities ON client.resID = facilities.resID WHERE client.resID =".$_GET["resID"];
$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());



while ($f = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { // loop as long as there are more results
    $names[] = $f['mname'];  // push to the array

print_r($names)

}
```

Let's say a restaurant have rice and potato. The print_r($names) are returning :

```
Array ( [0] => rice [1] => potato [2] => rice [3] => potato [4] => rice [5] => potato [6] => rice [7] => potato [8] => rice [9] => potato )
```

How could I solve this problem? Really appreciate your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query

```
SELECT client.resID AS resID, client.resName AS resName,
       menu.id AS mid, menu.name AS mname,
       facilities.name AS fname, facilities.id AS fid 
FROM client
INNER JOIN menu ON client.resID = menu.resID
INNER JOIN facilities ON client.resID = facilities.resID
WHERE client.resID =".$_GET["resID"]
```

returns as many occurences of "rice" as many times as the other two tables match. Since you are joining on the column set by `WHERE`, your query is effectively a cartesian product of the three joined tables (after filtering by `resID`).

ex.:

```
john rice fac1
john meat fac1
john rice fac2
john meat fac2
...
```

Perhaps you wanted to make three separate queries, one for each table

```
SELECT mid, mname FROM menu WHERE resID = $resID
```

Or maybe you wanted to join on some other column (say, one that is unique in all three tables)?

```
SELECT ...
FROM client
INNER JOIN menu ON client.resID = menu.id
INNER JOIN facilities ON client.resID = facilities.id
```

also note that including unescaped get parameters in the query string is dangerous, even if you *expect* numbers. Use [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or (at least) [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: If I use it this way, I will have trouble in my form. I can't update multiple tables with my form

Comment: @Jack look at the JOINed column. It's the same as the WHERE column.

Comment: Right, so MySQL would filter the rows of `client` first and then perform the joins with the other tables. I don't see a problem; there will be some repetition though, unless all tables share the same primary key :)

Comment: @Jack The fact that any reasonable SQL engine will use join buffers doesn't make it not a cartesian product. The result set is the same, you just avoid repeated scans, not repeated sending from the database.

Comment: @user1822825 what do you mean by "I can't update multiple tables with my form"? You can update each table with one UPDATE or INSERT query. It's up to you how you present it on the web page.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll try it and let you guys know my result. Thanks again :D

Comment: @Jack by cartesian product I meant that all selected rows from one table will be joined with all selected rows from the other tables.

Comment: Yeah okay, I see your point :) +1 ... though it's more likely to be a product of two tables, not three; without knowing the table structures that's just a guess though..

Answer (score 1):

use group by

```
$sql= "SELECT client.resID AS resID, client.resName AS resName, menu.id AS mid, 
       menu.name AS mname, facilities.name AS fname, facilities.id AS fid 
    FROM client 
    INNER JOIN menu ON client.resID = menu.resID 
    INNER JOIN facilities ON client.resID = facilities.resID 
    WHERE client.resID =".$_GET["resID"]." 
    group by mname ";
```

Comment: Please advocate proper escaping of variables.

Comment: Thanks :D but what if the facilities have some fields too. like facilities.name AS fname, facilities.id AS fid. If I use GROUP BY mname AND fname, it will only output 1 related row.

Comment: @user1822825 then most likely you'll need three separate queries. The you don't need the joins. See my answer.

Comment: @user1822825 you can use as many `while`s as you want. If you perform two different queries, you'll get two different result sets, and you can iterate over them in two different loops. Just be careful to not overwrite a variable (MySQL resource) before you use it - use different variables, or loop over before overwriting.

Comment: @user1822825 note that "form" usually refers to the user interface element that groups various inputs together (or to the physical equivalent thereof), not to the server script that handles the data from said inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As per Man Programmer said, you can use `Group By`:

```
$sql= "SELECT client.resID AS resID, client.resName AS resName, menu.id AS mid, menu.name AS mname, facilities.name AS fname, facilities.id AS fid FROM client INNER JOIN menu ON client.resID = menu.resID INNER JOIN facilities ON client.resID = facilities.resID WHERE client.resID =".$_GET["resID"]." group by mname ";
```

Or if you don't want Group By, you can use this kind of code.

```
 $items = array();
    $sql= "SELECT client.resID AS resID, client.resName AS resName, menu.id AS mid, menu.name AS mname, facilities.name AS fname, facilities.id AS fid FROM client INNER JOIN menu ON client.resID = menu.resID INNER JOIN facilities ON client.resID = facilities.resID WHERE client.resID =".$_GET["resID"];
    $q = mysql_query ( $sql ) or die( mysql_error() );
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $q ) ) {
     if( !in_array( $row['mname'],$items ) ) {
        $items[] = $row['mname'];
     }
    }

print_r( $items )
```

It will just skip the storing of value in the array if it detects that it already has that kind of value.

Comment: Use `$items[$row['mname']] = $row['mname'];` instead of `in_array()`.

Comment: Because `in_array()` is `O(n)` while a key based lookup is `O(log n)`

Comment: @Jack Or even `O(1)`. I would expect PHP to use a hash set for this purpose.

Comment: wow! you guys are geeks! I don't know what you're talking about.haha!

Comment: @ElsonSolano read: key-based lookup is much faster than `in_array`